# Just Audio Background Package in Flutterflow

Tags: flutter, just-audio

We are trying to implement the Just Audio background package within Flutterflow and it just crashes.

My question is:

Does anybody know of examples where the background package has been successfully implemented with Flutterflow? This way I can narrow down where the issue is coming from.

We tried everything possible for 3 days with no success.

```
// Automatic FlutterFlow imports
import '../../backend/backend.dart';
import '../../flutter_flow/flutter_flow_theme.dart';
import '../../flutter_flow/flutter_flow_util.dart';
import '../widgets/index.dart'; // Imports other custom widgets
import '../../flutter_flow/custom_functions.dart'; // Imports custom functions
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// Begin custom widget code
// DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY THE CODE ABOVE!

import 'package:audio_session/audio_session.dart';

import 'package:just_audio/just_audio.dart';
//import 'package:just_audio_background/just_audio_background.dart';
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

class AudioPlayer2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const AudioPlayer2({
    Key? key,
    this.width,
    this.height,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final double? width;
  final double? height;

  @override
  _AudioPlayer2State createState() => _AudioPlayer2State();
}

class _AudioPlayer2State extends State<AudioPlayer2> {
  static int _nextMediaId = 0;
  late AudioPlayer _player;
  final _playlist = ConcatenatingAudioSource(children: [
    // ClippingAudioSource(
    //   start: const Duration(seconds: 60),
    //   end: const Duration(seconds: 90),
    //   child: AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse(
    //       "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/unio-8cf9b.appspot.com/o/uploads%2FAmaterasu%20%E5%A4%A9%E7%85%A7%20%7C%20Goddess%20of%20the%20sun%20%7C%20432%20Hz.mp3?alt=media&token=6b897a0b-bb2c-47e9-bf60-422aa4e4acf2")),
    //   tag: MediaItem(
    //     id: '${_nextMediaId++}',
    //     album: "Science Friday",
    //     title: "A Salute To Head-Scratching Science (30 seconds)",
    //     artUri: Uri.parse(
    //         "https://media.wnyc.org/i/1400/1400/l/80/1/ScienceFriday_WNYCStudios_1400.jpg"),
    //   ),
    // ),
    // AudioSource.uri(
    //   Uri.parse(
    //       "https://s3.amazonaws.com/scifri-episodes/scifri20181123-episode.mp3"),
    //   tag: MediaItem(
    //     id: '${_nextMediaId++}',
    //     album: "Science Friday",
    //     title: "A Salute To Head-Scratching Science",
    //     artUri: Uri.parse(
    //         "https://media.wnyc.org/i/1400/1400/l/80/1/ScienceFriday_WNYCStudios_1400.jpg"),
    //   ),
    // ),
    // AudioSource.uri(
    //   Uri.parse("https://s3.amazonaws.com/scifri-segments/scifri201711241.mp3"),
    //   tag: MediaItem(
    //     id: '${_nextMediaId++}',
    //     album: "Science Friday",
    //     title: "From Cat Rheology To Operatic Incompetence",
    //     artUri: Uri.parse(
    //         "https://media.wnyc.org/i/1400/1400/l/80/1/ScienceFriday_WNYCStudios_1400.jpg"),
    //   ),
    // ),
    // AudioSource.uri(
    //   Uri.parse("asset:///audio/nature.mp3"),
    //   tag: MediaItem(
    //     id: '${_nextMediaId++}',
    //     album: "Public Domain",
    //     title: "Nature Sounds",
    //     artUri: Uri.parse(
    //         "https://media.wnyc.org/i/1400/1400/l/80/1/ScienceFriday_WNYCStudios_1400.jpg"),
    //   ),
    // ),
  ]);
  int _addedCount = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _player = AudioPlayer();

    _init();
  }

  Future<void> _init() async {
    final session = await AudioSession.instance;
    await session.configure(const AudioSessionConfiguration.speech());
    // Listen to errors during playback.
    _player.playbackEventStream.listen((event) {},
        onError: (Object e, StackTrace stackTrace) {
      print('A stream error occurred: $e');
    });
    try {
      await _player.setAudioSource(_playlist);
    } catch (e, stackTrace) {
      // Catch load errors: 404, invalid url ...
      print("Error loading playlist: $e");
      print(stackTrace);
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _player.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Stream<PositionData> get _positionDataStream =>
      Rx.combineLatest3<Duration, Duration, Duration?, PositionData>(
          _player.positionStream,
          _player.bufferedPositionStream,
          _player.durationStream,
          (position, bufferedPosition, duration) => PositionData(
              position, bufferedPosition, duration ?? Duration.zero));

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              ControlButtons(_player),
              StreamBuilder<PositionData>(
                stream: _positionDataStream,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  final positionData = snapshot.data;
                  return SeekBar(
                    duration: positionData?.duration ?? Duration.zero,
                    position: positionData?.position ?? Duration.zero,
                    bufferedPosition:
                        positionData?.bufferedPosition ?? Duration.zero,
                    onChangeEnd: (newPosition) {
                      _player.seek(newPosition);
                    },
                  );
                },
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ControlButtons extends StatelessWidget {
  final AudioPlayer player;

  const ControlButtons(this.player, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(
            Icons.volume_up,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            showSliderDialog(
              context: context,
              title: "Adjust volume",
              divisions: 10,
              min: 0.0,
              max: 1.0,
              stream: player.volumeStream,
              onChanged: player.setVolume,
            );
          },
        ),
        StreamBuilder<SequenceState?>(
          stream: player.sequenceStateStream,
          builder: (context, snapshot) => IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.skip_previous,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            onPressed: player.hasPrevious ? player.seekToPrevious : null,
          ),
        ),
        StreamBuilder<PlayerState>(
          stream: player.playerStateStream,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            final playerState = snapshot.data;
            final processingState = playerState?.processingState;
            final playing = playerState?.playing;
            if (processingState == ProcessingState.loading ||
                processingState == ProcessingState.buffering) {
              return Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                width: 64.0,
                height: 64.0,
                child: const CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            } else if (playing != true) {
              return IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(
                  Icons.play_arrow,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                iconSize: 64.0,
                onPressed: player.play,
              );
            } else if (processingState != ProcessingState.completed) {
              return IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(
                  Icons.pause,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                iconSize: 64.0,
                onPressed: player.pause,
              );
            } else {
              return IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(
                  Icons.replay,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                iconSize: 64.0,
                onPressed: () => player.seek(Duration.zero,
                    index: player.effectiveIndices!.first),
              );
            }
          },
        ),
        StreamBuilder<SequenceState?>(
          stream: player.sequenceStateStream,
          builder: (context, snapshot) => IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.skip_next,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            onPressed: player.hasNext ? player.seekToNext : null,
          ),
        ),
        StreamBuilder<double>(
          stream: player.speedStream,
          builder: (context, snapshot) => IconButton(
            icon: Text("${snapshot.data?.toStringAsFixed(1)}x",
                style: const TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white)),
            onPressed: () {
              showSliderDialog(
                context: context,
                title: "Adjust speed",
                divisions: 10,
                min: 0.5,
                max: 1.5,
                stream: player.speedStream,
                onChanged: player.setSpeed,
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class SeekBar extends StatefulWidget {
  final Duration duration;
  final Duration position;
  final Duration bufferedPosition;
  final ValueChanged<Duration>? onChanged;
  final ValueChanged<Duration>? onChangeEnd;

  const SeekBar({
    Key? key,
    required this.duration,
    required this.position,
    required this.bufferedPosition,
    this.onChanged,
    this.onChangeEnd,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  SeekBarState createState() => SeekBarState();
}

class SeekBarState extends State<SeekBar> {
  double? _dragValue;
  late SliderThemeData _sliderThemeData;

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();

    _sliderThemeData = SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith(
      trackHeight: 2.0,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        SliderTheme(
          data: _sliderThemeData.copyWith(
            thumbShape: RoundSliderThumbShape(enabledThumbRadius: 0.0),
            activeTrackColor: Colors.white,
            inactiveTrackColor: Colors.grey.shade300,
          ),
          child: ExcludeSemantics(
            child: Slider(
              min: 0.0,
              max: widget.duration.inMilliseconds.toDouble(),
              value: min(widget.bufferedPosition.inMilliseconds.toDouble(),
                  widget.duration.inMilliseconds.toDouble()),
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  _dragValue = value;
                });
                if (widget.onChanged != null) {
                  widget.onChanged!(Duration(milliseconds: value.round()));
                }
              },
              onChangeEnd: (value) {
                if (widget.onChangeEnd != null) {
                  widget.onChangeEnd!(Duration(milliseconds: value.round()));
                }
                _dragValue = null;
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
        SliderTheme(
          data: _sliderThemeData.copyWith(
            inactiveTrackColor: Colors.transparent,
          ),
          child: Slider(
            min: 0.0,
            max: widget.duration.inMilliseconds.toDouble(),
            value: min(_dragValue ?? widget.position.inMilliseconds.toDouble(),
                widget.duration.inMilliseconds.toDouble()),
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                _dragValue = value;
              });
              if (widget.onChanged != null) {
                widget.onChanged!(Duration(milliseconds: value.round()));
              }
            },
            onChangeEnd: (value) {
              if (widget.onChangeEnd != null) {
                widget.onChangeEnd!(Duration(milliseconds: value.round()));
              }
              _dragValue = null;
            },
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          right: 16.0,
          bottom: 0.0,
          child: Text(
              RegExp(r'((^0*[1-9]\d*:)?\d{2}:\d{2})\.\d+$')
                      .firstMatch("$_remaining")
                      ?.group(1) ??
                  '$_remaining',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Duration get _remaining => widget.duration - widget.position;
}

class PositionData {
  final Duration position;
  final Duration bufferedPosition;
  final Duration duration;

  PositionData(this.position, this.bufferedPosition, this.duration);
}

void showSliderDialog({
  required BuildContext context,
  required String title,
  required int divisions,
  required double min,
  required double max,
  String valueSuffix = '',
  required Stream<double> stream,
  required ValueChanged<double> onChanged,
}) {
  showDialog<void>(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
      title: Text(title, textAlign: TextAlign.center),
      content: StreamBuilder<double>(
        stream: stream,
        builder: (context, snapshot) => SizedBox(
          height: 100.0,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text('${snapshot.data?.toStringAsFixed(1)}$valueSuffix',
                  style: const TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'Fixed',
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 24.0)),
              Slider(
                divisions: divisions,
                min: min,
                max: max,
                value: snapshot.data ?? 1.0,
                onChanged: onChanged,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: did you manage get this working. I have also been trying with just_audio_background, and also audio_service but nothing has worked so far. It seems like we need to edit the main().dart file to have an intirialistion for the service.